# how can i make remove this parent , but dont want to skill 1 or 2 chirldren?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some code below:

```html
 <ul class="history"> 
      <li class="hello"></li>
      <li class="hi"></li>
      <li class="yello"></li>
      <div class="baby"></div>
      <div class="kitty"></div>
    </ul>
```

now i want remove some elements in ul, but i want hold 1 div or li (ex: div.baby) how can i do now? i want use click function.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not a valid HTML, div can't be direct child for ul

Comment: div not use in ul? i dont know that

Comment: what about <a> ? can i use in <ul>?

Comment: see http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html#ul-content-model - the only permitted child of `ul` is the `li` element

Answer (score 1):

with jQuery:

```
var babyElement = $('.baby') // save element for later
$('.yellow').remove() // remove element
```

with JavaScript:

```
var babyElement = document.querySelector('.baby')
var yellowElement = document.querySelector('.yellow')
if (yellowElement.parentNode) {
  yellowElement.parentNode.removeChild(yellowElement)
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is you want:

```
$('ul.history').children().not('.baby').remove();
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7kmfbtpm/1/)